# Unable to run ZMQStream with Tornado Event loop using python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, tornado, zeromq, distributed-computing, pyzmq

I've been trying to set up a server / client using zmq eventloop for **`REQ / REP`** messaging. Since python 3 doesn't support the eventloop provided by zmq, I'm trying to run it with tornado's eventloop.

I'm facing issues running zmqStream with tornado's event loop using python 3.

I created the server / client code using zmq's zmqStream and tornado's eventloop. The client is sending the correct messages, but the server doesn't seem to be responding to the message requests.

The server side code:

```
from tornado import ioloop
import zmq

def echo(stream, msg):
   stream.send_pyobj(msg)

ctx = zmq.Context()
socket = ctx.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5678')
stream = ZMQStream(socket)
stream.on_recv(echo)
ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

The client side code:

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5678")

for request in range (1,10):
   print("Sending request ", request,"...")
   socket.send_string("Hello")
   # Get the reply.
   message = socket.recv_pyobj()
   print("Received reply ", request, "[", message, "]")
```

I was expecting the server to return back the request messages being sent by the client. But it is just not responding to the requests being sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> server doesn't seem to be responding

### Step 0:

One server-side SLOC, `stream = ZMQStream( socket )` calls a function, that is not MCVE-documented and must and does fail to execute to yield any result: `"ZMQStream" in dir()` confirms this with **`False`**

**Remedy:**
repair the MCVE and also `print( zmq.zmq_version )` + `"ZMQStream" in dir()` confirmation

---

### Step 1:

Always prevent infinite deadlocks, unless due reason exists not to do so, with setting prior to doing respective `.bind()` or `.connect()` **`<aSocket>.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER, 0 )`**. Hung forever applications and un-released (yes, you read it correctly, infinitely blocked) resources are not welcome in distributed computing systems.

---

### Step 2:

Avoid a blind distributed-mutual-deadlock the **`REQ/REP`** is always prone to run into. It will happen, one just never knows when. You may read heaps of details about this on Stack Overflow.

And remedy? May (and shall, where possible) avoid using the blocking-forms of `.recv()`-s (fair `.poll()`-s are way smarter-design-wise, resources-wise) may use additional sender-side signalisation before "throwing" either side into infinitely-blocking `.recv()`-s (yet a network delivery failure or other reason for a silent message drop may cause soft-signaling to flag sending, which did not result in receiving and mutual-deadlocking, where hard-wired behaviour moves both of the REQ/REP side into waiting one for the other, to send a message (which the counterparty will never send, as it is also waiting for `.recv()`-ing the still not received one from the (still listening) opposite side ))

---

### Last, but not least:

The ZeroMQ Zen-of-Zero has also a Zero-Warranty - as messages are either fully delivered (error-free) or not delivered at all. The `REQ/REP` mutual deadlocks are best resolvable if one never falls into them (ref. `LINGER` and `poll()` above)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was looking into the documentation of zmq and it says that “ZMQStream objects let you register callbacks to handle messages as they arrive, for use with the tornado eventloop.”.  Can we use ZMQStream with asyncio ?

Comment: Always welcome, @AlokNathSaha + Could you kindly adapt the MCVE-code so as to show, where does the ZMQStream come from and add some persistent URL direction to a copy of the documentation that you cite from? That would be great. In the above documented state, Python, after the MCVE-imports so far has no clue what to do once the call to a ZMQStream(...) has appeared on the current program-execution line. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Sir. I did not understand step 0. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: @Avv: I am afraid that user3666197 has taken something of a leave of absence from the site (see the message on their profile). Perhaps you can ask a new question? Make sure you show your code, describe your problem accurately, and provide any input data as appropriate. Thanks!